# Função para verificação/check de Upload de Imagem

Tags: php, upload

**Meu código:**

```
   //return > 0 is ok!
    function _fileinput($name) {
        var_dump($name);
        $input['arquivo']        = $_FILES["$name"]["name"];
        $input['arquivo']        = strtolower(str_replace("h","",$input['arquivo']));
        $input['mimetype']       = $_FILES["$name"]["type"];
        $input['temp']           = $_FILES["$name"]["tmp_name"];
        $input['mimetypes']      = array("image/jpeg", "image/png");
        $input['extencoes']      = array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png");
        $input['extencao']       = strtolower(end(explode(".",$input['arquivo'])));
        $input['mimetype']        = strtolower($input['mimetype']);
        $input['novo']           = "[fi]"."[".date('Y-m')."]"."[".strtolower($name)."]"."[".rand(1000,9999)."]".".".$input['extencao'];

        var_dump($input);

        $x              = 0;
        if ((array_search($input['extencao'], $input['extencoes']) !== FALSE) AND (array_search(mimetype, $input['mimetypes']) !== FALSE)) {
            $x++;
        }
        else {
            $x = 0;
        }
        var_dump($x);

        list($largura, $altura) = getimagesize($input['temp']);
        if ($largura == "" || $altura == "") {
            $x = 0;
        }
        else { 
            $x++; 
        }
        var_dump($x);

        if ($x == 2) {
            return $input['novo'];
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
        var_dump($x);

    }
```

Versão pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/nZcUJEHQ

**Modo de usar:**

```
$fileinput = _fileinput("foto");
if ($fileinput > 0) {
        echo $fileinput; //nome para o arquivo
}
else {
    echo "deny upload!";
}
```

**Problema:**

Não retorna o novo nome para o arquivo, a função no pastebin não funciona, por que ?

**Referencias do código:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro que poste o código do pastebin aqui, muitos que podem te ajudar, podem não ter acesso a este site. Eu mesmo, no momento, não tenho acesso. Pra saber o que postar do seu código, recomento que leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)

Comment: Inserido como informado

Comment: Sem muita análise, sugeria que removesses as aspas duplas de dentro dos parênteses retos que contêm nomes de variáveis - `$_FILES["$name"]["name"]` para `$_FILES[$name]["name"]` - Faça isso para o script todo, existem várias partes do código onde as variáveis aparecem entre aspas dentro desses parênteses.

Comment: `strtolower(end(explode(".",$input['arquivo'])));` isso aqui gera um warning.

Comment: O problema não era apenas este, existiam outros relacionados a lógica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta linha aqui vai retornar um erro, do tipo `Strict Standards`

```
strtolower(end(explode(".",$input['arquivo'])));
```

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in: ... line

Significa que deves apenas passar uma variável verdadeira, e não uma função que retorna uma array.

Assim sendo, em vez disto:

```
strtolower(end(explode(".",$input['arquivo'])));
```

Faça isto:

```
$input['ext'] = explode(".",$input['arquivo']);
strtolower('.' . end($input['ext']));
```

Outra parte é a condição que usaste para procurar a extensão e o tipo MIME na array. A função `array_search`, procura numa array o valor especificado, mas ela não retorna `true` ao encontrar esse valor. Retorna o índice desse valor, que pode até ser `0` que é o equivalente a `false`. Nesse caso, o teu contador `$x` nunca chega a sair do `0`, ou até pode, se o valor de ambos os índices for diferente de `0`.

O correto seria usar a função, `in_array`, que verifica se determinado valor existe numa array, e retorna `true` ou `false` para o caso de não encontrar esse valor.

Onde tens:

```
((array_search($input['extencao'], $input['extencoes']) !== FALSE) AND (array_search(mimetype, $input['mimetypes']) !== FALSE))
```

Faça isto:

```
((in_array($input['extencao'], $input['extencoes'])) AND (in_array($input['mimetype'], $input['mimetypes'])))
```

Com as mudanças efetuadas o script ficaria assim:

```
function _fileinput($name) {

    $input['arquivo']        = $_FILES[$name]["name"];
    $input['arquivo']        = strtolower(str_replace("h","",$input['arquivo']));
    $input['mimetype']       = $_FILES[$name]["type"];
    $input['temp']           = $_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"];
    $input['mimetypes']      = array("image/jpeg", "image/png");
    $input['extencoes']      = array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png");
    $input['ext']            = explode("." , $input['arquivo']);
    $input['extencao']       = strtolower('.'.end($input['ext']));
    $input['mimetype']        = strtolower($input['mimetype']);
    $input['novo']           = "[fi]"."[".date('Y-m')."]"."[".strtolower($name)."]"."[".rand(1000,9999)."]".".".$input['extencao'];



    $x = 0;
    if ((in_array($input['extencao'], $input['extencoes'])) AND (in_array($input['mimetype'], $input['mimetypes']))) {
        $x+=1;
    }
    else {
        $x = 0;
    }


    list($largura, $altura) = getimagesize($input['temp']);
    if ($largura == "" || $altura == "") {
        $x = 0;
    }
    else { 
        $x++; 
    }

    if ($x == 2) {
        return $input['novo'];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}

print _fileinput('ficheiro');
```

**Algumas Referências:**

- [In_Array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)